# MFC: disable New File and Save File features in SDI application

Tags: file, visual-c++, mfc

What would be the easiest way of using commands in the code to programatically disable these two features in an application? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could handle the update UI message:

```
ON_UPDATE_COMMAND_UI(ID_FILE_NEW, OnUpdateFileNew)
ON_UPDATE_COMMAND_UI(ID_FILE_SAVE, OnUpdateFileSave)

...

void CMainFrame::OnUpdateFileNew(CCmdUI *pCmdUI)
{
    pCmdUI->Enable( FALSE );
}

void CMainFrame::OnUpdateFileSave(CCmdUI *pCmdUI)
{
    pCmdUI->Enable( FALSE );
}
```

Comment: Ok, fixed that typo (should have properly read the code after copying from an existing project!)

Answer (score 1):

Override `CWinApp::OnFileNew` with your own function, as shown below.

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMyApp, CWinApp)
    ON_COMMAND(ID_APP_ABOUT, &CMyApp::OnAppAbout)
    // Standard file based document commands
    **//ON_COMMAND(ID_FILE_NEW, &CWinApp::OnFileNew)**
    ON_COMMAND(ID_FILE_NEW, &CMyApp::OnFileNew)
    ON_COMMAND(ID_FILE_OPEN, &CWinApp::OnFileOpen)
    // Standard print setup command
    ON_COMMAND(ID_FILE_PRINT_SETUP, &CWinApp::OnFilePrintSetup)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()


void CMyApp::OnFileNew()
{
         //Create a static member variable to hold the state. For the first time create a docment. From next time avoid calling CWinApp::OnFileNew();
    if( m_bDocCreated == FALSE )
    {
        CString strMsg;
        strMsg.Format( L"Create New DOC" );
        AfxMessageBox( strMsg );

        CWinApp::OnFileNew();
        m_bDocCreated = TRUE;
    }
    else
    {
        CFrameWnd* pFrame = (CFrameWnd*)AfxGetMainWnd();
        CMyDoc* pDoc = (CMyDoc*)pFrame->GetActiveDocument();
        CString strMsg;
        strMsg.Format( L"Doc ID = %ld",pDoc->m_lIndex );
        AfxMessageBox( strMsg );

    }


}
```

Answer (score -1):

Call `CMenu::EnableMenuItem` with the appropriate menu items and `MF_DISABLED` as the second parameter. Here's the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h62wh3y1%28VS.80%29.aspx).